# Assigning value to a column based on the number of entries in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My df is

| assistant | date | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday |
| AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday |
| TM | 2022-02-28 | not holiday |
| AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday |
| .. | .......... | ....... |
| TM | 2022-03-18 | not holiday |
| AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday |

'assistant' can have one of many names.
date is a mix of dates, date is not the index.
day tells you if it is a holiday

I need to add a new column 'Value' which should have a value of 2  for the first 20 values of an assistant on a date that is a holiday and 3 if more than 20.

To clarify this is to give value to an assistants activity (sale number for eg)on a holiday. For the first 20 sales by that assistant his value is 2 and from 21st sale onwards on the same day it will be 3.

Sorry for being verbose instead of providing the code.

The expected output

| Ind | assistant | date | day | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday | 2 |
| 2 | AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday | 2 |
| 3 | AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday | 2 |
| 4 | AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday | 2 |
| .. | .......... | ....... | . |  |
| 20 | AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday | 2 |
| 21 | AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday | 3 |
| 22 | AJ | 2022-02-27 | holiday | 3 |

Comment: added the expected output

Comment: Both inputs and outputs are extrapolated tables. From the input df select rows that correspond to holidays and if AJ is the assistant on a holiday set value = 2 for the first 20 entries and value = 3 from the 21st entry onwards

Answer (score 0):

This might get you heading in the right direction:

```
def af(x):
    day_value = x['day'].iat[0]

    if day_value == 'holiday':
        rc = ([2]*min(len(x), 20) + ([3]*(len(x)-20) if len(x)>20 else []))
    else:
        rc = [1]*len(x)
        
    return pd.DataFrame({'day': pd.Series([day_value]*len(x)), 'value': pd.Series(rc)})


ndf = df.groupby(by=['assistant','date']).apply(af).reset_index()

ndf['ind'] = ndf['level_2'] + 1
ndf[['ind','assistant','date','day','value']]

    ind assistant         date          day  value
0     1       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
1     2       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
2     3       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
3     4       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
4     5       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
..........
15   16       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
16   17       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
17   18       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
18   19       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
19   20       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      2
20   21       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      3
21   22       AJ   2022-02-27       holiday      3
22    1       TM   2022-02-28   not holiday      1
```